# Function 'convertX' in 'ggforest'

Tags: r

Can anyone help me to fix the this error below? Thank you in advance.

```
**surv_object1 = Surv(time=dt$OS,event=dt$Status)
fit.coxph1 <- coxph(surv_object1 ~ Age + Gender + Pathology, data = dt)
ggforest(fit.coxph1, data = dt,main = "OS")**
```

Error in convertX(unit(theme_get()$text$size, "pt"), "mm") :
could not find function "convertX**

Comment: You should look at the package DESCRIPTION file and note which other packages are imported or otherwise listed as being dependencies. `Version: 0.4.9
Depends: ggplot2, ggpubr (≥ 0.1.6)
Imports: grid, gridExtra (≥ 2.0), magrittr, maxstat, methods, scales, survival, stats, broom, dplyr, tidyr, survMisc, purrr, tibble, rlang, ggtext (≥ 0.1.0)
Suggests: knitr, flexsurv, cmprsk, markdown, testthat, rmarkdown`

Comment: It is fixed after the packages of broom and grid are imported.